# Is there a way to auto-increment ID's on UserForms

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a data entry `UserForm` for sales leads (very new to VBA). All of the data collected will be written out a "Lead Data" worksheet.

Each lead requires a Unique `LeadID`. This needs to be populated in a textbox on the Userform and written out to `"Lead Data"` in an ID column alongside all other information.

I am struggling to find a way of

1. Finding the last ID used on "Lead Data", setting to 1 if nothing present already.
2. Adding 1 to this and setting the value of the TextBox to this value

I've done some digging on various forums and the below code has been suggested but this does not reference "Lead Data"

I am also unclear as to whether this should be on the Form Activation event or Initialization.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

 Dim LstRw As Long

 LstRw = .Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

 Col.A after adding 1 to it.
 Me.tbLeadID.Value = .Cells(LstRw, "I").Value + 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this by referring target sheet,

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

 Dim LstRw As Long

 LstRw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lead Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

' Col.A after adding 1 to it.
 Me.tbLeadID.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lead Data").Cells(LstRw, "I").Value + 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be on Initialise, otherwise it would increase if you switched away and back again.   Personally ! would use Max() to find the largest value in whichever column you're storing the ID in. If that's column A then I would write

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.TxtLeadID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")) + 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both for your suggestions, this moved my understanding forward.

I actually went a slightly different direction, and have solved the problem for the time being.

I have recorded a     NextID field on one of my reference worksheets.

This is pulled back onto the     UserForm on initialize.

```
tbLeadID.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherRefData").Range("H2").Value
```

Then when the userform is saved using the save button

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherRefData").Range("H2").Value = 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherRefData").Range("H2").Value + 1
```

Open to feedback on this!